# jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(View) deprecated in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

After checking **Radio button** I want to call `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(View)` method but seems like this method is **deprecated**.

**What is new api for this method?**

Code:

```
if (currentLanguage.equals(getString(R.string.LANGUAGE_ENGLISH), ignoreCase = true)) {
   settingsRadiogroup.check(radioButtonEn.id)
   jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(settingsRadiogroup) //deprecated
} else {
   settingsRadiogroup.check(radioButtonBn.id)
   jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(settingsRadiogroup) //deprecated
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` was passing a Drawable inside. Quoting developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompat.html#jumpToCurrentState(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)):

> This method was deprecated in API level 27.1.0. Use jumpToCurrentState() directly. Call Drawable.jumpToCurrentState().

So in this case, `settingsRadiogroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` should not show any deprecation.